# How to bundle the JS loaded by script manager from CDN in Asp.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, scriptmanager, asp.net-bundling

I have an application in asp.net, I am using a script manager in master page. I want to load all the scripts related to script manager from CDN and hence I have placed EnableCDN="true" in script manager.

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnableCdn="true" />
```

I have noticed that all the scripts are loaded separately this increases the http requests, I want to bundle all of them into 1 script.

Has anyone achieved this bundling the scripts loaded from CDN into 1 js file instead of separate in asp.net(Not MVC)?

Below is the snap of all js that is getting loaded separately
[image: Below is the snap of all js that is getting loaded separately]

Answer (score 0):

Only application relative URLs (~/url) are allowed to be included in `ScriptBundle`, Using CDN in bundles is supported only at the top bundle level.

You could upload the entire bundle to a CDN after building it yourself and us it like `https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.6/1/MsAjaxJs.js`.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/MsAjaxJs", "https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.6/1/MsAjaxJs.js").Include(
    "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjax.js",
    "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxApplicationServices.js",
    "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxTimer.js",
    "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js"));
```

Also, optimizations are enabled when compilation is set to `false` in `web.config` file